# Creating a uniform Eigen expression with a fake size (to save memory)

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm working on some CFD code and for some constants (such as surface roughness), I would like to provide the option of either setting it to a uniform value for the whole field, or to non-uniform values.
I would prefer both options to be represented as `Eigen::DenseBase` derivatives, so that I can simply use function templates for both options.

**Non-uniform** values are currently represented as `ArrayXXd`s, where each column represents a cell. However, using that type for **uniform** fields would be an enormous waste of space: Those values are never changed, so they don't need individual representation.

So what I want is to just store a single column vector, which then behaves as if it had the same number of columns as the non-uniform version (e.g. allows access via `operator()` or `.col(Index)`).
I could probably do this with a wrapper class, but then I'd likely be [reinventing the square wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel#Related_phrases).

I looked into creating a [custom nullary expression](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizing_NullaryExpr.html) but I don't think that's the right path, because AFAICT that still uses the same amount of memory.

If what I'm looking for is not possible with an Eigen type, I'll also accept that as an answer and will just use a wrapper.

Comment: Do you want a [`DenseBase::Constant`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#aed89b5cc6e3b7d9d5bd63aed245ccd6d)? (Not entirely sure what you mean by uniform). Also, a NullaryExpression will take about the size of the included functor object, plus two `long int` for the dimension (optional, if known at compile-time). What made you assume that it uses the same amount of memory as an `ArrayXXd`?

Comment: Well, I ran a not-so-thorough benchmark of an ```ArrayXXd::Constant``` before asking this question and it seemed to consume just as much memory as when declaring an ```ArrayXXd``` of the same size and then calling ```setConstant``` on it.

Comment: What operations are you doing/benchmarking? (Provide a [mre] ...)

Comment: On the word "uniform": At least in this context, a field can be constant, as in that it can't be changed (=```const```) but have different values in each cell. A uniform field would have the same value everywhere (which is what ```EigenBase::Constant``` does...)

Comment: Ok, with what you said I went back and found my benchmark to be stupid. ```EigenBase::Constant``` indeed barely uses any memory.
But it doesn't quite solve my problem, because as described in the OP, I basically need a broadcasted column vector. But I'll look into a NullaryExpression again (though maybe ```Replicate``` already does what I need)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure this should even be an answer, because it's equal to "RTFM".

With guidance from [chtz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6870253/chtz), I revisited the functionality Eigen already provides, which I had previously dismissed based on a poorly written benchmark. But it's all already there in the library:

[Replicate](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Replicate.html) does exactly what I want.